Is there a reason to keep $T_F$ abstract in su(N) algebras?
In physics, calculations involving the su(N) algebra often leave results in terms of $T_F$.
For example, one can find things like
$$\beta_0 = \frac{11}{3}N - \frac{4}{3} T_F n_f.$$
$T_F$ is defined as the normalisation of the generators of the fundamental representation of su(N) ($\mathrm{Tr}(t^a t^b) = T_F \delta^{ab}$), and as far as I know, it is equal to $T_F=\frac{1}{2}$.
Now, I can understand that one leaves $N$ unspecified since you might want your result to be general, and also that some constants, like the Casimir, are also not written explicitly as a matter of "simplicity", since $C_F=\frac{N^2-1}{2N}$.
However, I find it puzzling to see the advantage of writing $T_F$ instead of $\frac{1}{2}$, especially because it is usually multiplied by rational coefficients that could perfectly absorb the factors of 2.
I would understand leaving $T_F$ general if the calculations could be generalised to other representations by the substitution $T_F \to T_G$ (and maybe similar replacements for other quantities); however, this doesn't seem to be the case as far as I'm aware.
Thus, my question is whether, from a mathematical point of view, there is any reason to keep $T_F$ abstract instead of substituting its exact value. Is my understanding that $T_F=\frac{1}{2}$ wrong?
